# Java: Checking if an attribute is set with int and Integer

Tags: java, types

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
Public Class Test{
    int a;
}
```

At some point in my program I want to check whether attribute a is set. I know that if I used Integer instead of int as the type of the attribute I could do something like:

```
if(test.a!=null)
    ...;
```

But what if I keep the int there and instead and use this to check:

```
if(test.a!=0)
    ...;
```

One problem is that I wouldn't be able to differentiate between a zero value and an unset value, but in my program those are the same, as valid values are all different from 0. Also, using int simplifies things I need to do later on, like comparisons using == .

So would it be fine to use int here, or Integer is always preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's totally up to you, either is fine (provided "unset" and `0` **really** mean the same thing in your program). I realize that's not much of an answer, but it's the truth. :-) If "unset" and `0` didn't mean the same thing, that would argue more strongly for `Integer` so you could properly differentiate them.

Re your comment below:

> I just wanted confirmation that an unset int will always be equal to `0`

Yes, `int` is always initialized to `0`, per [Section 4.12.5 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Comment: Well yeah this helped. I needed the confirmation that if "unset" and 0 are the same then using int is fine, and that on other cases it's better to go with Integer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The int primitive type will be initialized to `0` when the declaration does not specify a value (like in your code snippet above).

If the state "set/unset" (instead of the value) is important for your program, you could use an Integer (as you mention), a boolean dirty flag or a "magic number".

If you want to compare to a magic number, I'd advice against something as common as the default value `0`. Use something that you will hardly find in your program, like Integer.MIN_VALUE and guard against it in your setter.

In that case, you could do something like:

```
public class Test {
   private static final int MAGIC_NR = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   private int var = MAGIC_NR; //set it to the magic nr at declaration time  

   public boolean isVarSet() {
      return var == MAGIC_NR;
   }

   public void setVar(int value) {
       if (value == MAGIC_NR) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for VarX"); // guard against setting this value - otherwise you're in trouble
       var = value;
   }

   public int getVar() {
       return var;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fine from a convention standpoint, although you'll probably want to use a constant to symbolize the unset value:

```
public static final int UNSET = 0;
...
if(test.a == UNSET) {
....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you want to access it, I'm not entirely clear on how this works but my understanding is a static variable doesn't need to be instantiated, its already an object so you could try something like this.

```
    public class Test {
        public static int a;
    }
```

Then refer to it by referring to the Test class,

```
    if (Test.a != null) {}
```

Or of course you could simply create an object of the Test class where ever you want to refer to the variable.

```
    Test test = new Test();
    if (test.a != null) {}
```

And finally my third solution would be to pass it into the constructor of the new class.

```
    public class NewCLass {
         int newInt;  
         public NewClass(int num1) {
            this.newInt = num1;
         }
    }
```

then when you created an object of that class you'd have to pass an int into the constructor, or use mulitple constructors. As for your last question use what ever you want, I rarely use the Integer class unless I need to use a static method from it or something along those lines. I prefer to use int. Hope that helped.

Comment: Your understanding of static is incorrect. In your example all instances of `Test` will share the same value of `Test.a`. This is a good starting point to learn about static members: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Well like I said, I was unsure but thank you for correcting me. It is one way to refer to an int from another class. Maybe the question just wasn't clear enough, I thought that's he was asking.